# Attribute Error : 'OLSResults' object has no attribute forecast

Tags: python, statsmodels, attributeerror, forecasting

When running the following script, a error message is displayed after forecast=model.forecast.
Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('testregressiondata.xlsx')


y = df['Load']
X_all = df[['HDDs', 'Wind']]`
X_labels = ['HDDs', 'Wind']
```

## get user input for independent variables to include and exclude

```
while True:
    print(f'Independent variables in dataset: {X_labels}')
    include = input('Enter independent variables to include (comma-separated): ')
    exclude = input('Enter independent variables to exclude (comma-separated): ')
    if include == '' and exclude == '':
        print('Please enter at least one independent variable to include or exclude.')
    else:
        include = include.split(',') if include else []
        exclude = exclude.split(',') if exclude else []
        if not set(include).issubset(X_labels):
            print('One or more included independent variables are not in the dataset.')
        elif not set(exclude).issubset(X_labels):
            print('One or more excluded independent variables are not in the dataset.')
        else:
            break
```

## filter independent variables based on user input

```
X_labels = [x for x in X_labels if x not in exclude]
X_labels += include
X = X_all[X_labels]
```

## add constant to independent variables

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
```

## perform regression analysis

```
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

## print regression results

```
print(model.summary())
```

## perform dynamic forecast for next 5 periods

```
forecast = model.forecast(steps=5, exog=X[-5:])
forecast_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[-1], periods=5, freq='M')
```

## create graph with line of best fit from forecast

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, y, label='Actual Data')
ax.plot(forecast_index, forecast, label='Forecasted Data')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
ax.legend()
```

## show graph with line of best fit from forecast

```
plt.show()
```

Any ideas of what I could fix? All help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You need to replace from `model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()` to `model = sm.OLS(y, X); model.fit()` cause execution of fit method returns new object instead of model instance

Comment: Rustam, I changed the code to your suggestion: model =sm.OLS(y, X); model.fit(); print(model.summary); I am recieving an OLS error object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: Only time series models (in `tsa`) know how to `forecast`. The models outside `tsa` like OLS do not have a time axis and are mainly cross-sectional. Those have `predict` for given exog.